# $.scrollTo() function horizontally?

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I don't really clearly understand the scrollTo() plugin function.

What I'm trying to do is to go to the specific target horizontally (like one scene to another scene). Here's some of my codes:

```
<div class="left" style="cursor:pointer;"><a href="#" onclick="$.scrollTo( '#menu', 800, {easing:'elasout'} );"> < </a></div>
<div class="right" style="cursor:pointer;"><a href="#" onclick="$.scrollTo( '#city', 800, {easing:'elasout'} );"> > </a></div>
<div class="name" style="cursor:pointer;"><a href="#" onclick="$.scrollTo( '#nature', 800, {easing:'elasout'} );" > NatureVille</a></div>
```

It's not working at all. Could anyone kindly simplify or explain the right direction to this problem ASAP?

Thank you so much. (Jquery lib and scrollTo.js are already included.)

P.S. please excuse my messy code, I'm kinda new in this. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [the `scrollTo` documentation](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html).
You should set it up with the `axis` param:

```
$.scrollTo( '#menu', 800, {easing:'elasout', axis:'y'} );
```

Or, you can give the target as a hash:

```
$.scrollTo( '#menu', {top:0 , left:800}, {easing:'elasout'} );
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much sir, this works, but i don't get the effect of easing. It just instantly go to the targeted location. :(

Comment: Well, I didn't check it but, "elasout" may not be a valid easing type ;)